# sed scripting : how to search after n no. of lines?

Tags: sed

How to capture the first occurrence of a pattern using grep after 'n' numbers of lines in a large size file ?

For instance,
I have 1000 lines of code in which 'wire' occur before and after 451st line.
I want to grab the first occurrence of wire after 451st line .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use sed's range expressions to perform this task easily. For example:

```
sed -n '452,$ { /wire/ {p;q} }' /tmp/foo
```

This will skip the first 451 lines, then scan each line until EOF for "wire." When found, it will print the pattern space and then quit.

Comment: Hi ! I want to use this command in Tcl script for that I have changed this command as follow :                                           set MIDLINE2 [ exec sed -n {1134,${/wire/{=;q}}} foo.txt ]            It gives me correct answer but in place 1134 I want to use variable $MIDLINE that has value 1134. How can I do that ? Please suggest me some way..

Comment: @user1468315 Please ask that as a separate question, and not as a comment. I'd be very glad to answer it there as a TCL question.