# Using a Variable in a sed command called in Tcl Script

Tags: tcl

I want to use the following command in a tcl script :

```
sed -n '452,$ { /wire/ {p;q} }' /tmp/foo
```

For that I have changed this command as follow :

```
set MIDLINE2 [ exec sed -n {1134,$ {/wire/{=;q}}} foo.txt ]
```

It gives me correct answer but in place 1134 I want to use variable $MIDLINE that has value  1134. How can I do that ? Please suggest some way.

Comment: Question is a follow-up related to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11114250/1301972).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simple problem of quoting. You're using curly braces which inhibits variable substitution. Since you want variable substitution you need to use something else.

```
set MIDLINE2 [ exec sed -n "$MIDLINE,\$ {/wire/{=;q}}" foo.txt ]
```

Notice that you have to put a backslash in front of the literal `$`, otherwise Tcl will try to substitute that, too.

Comment: +1 Technically, the dollar sign does not have to be escaped. Variable substitution only happens when the dollar sign is followed by a variable name, an open parenthesis or an open brace -- http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M12

Comment: @user1468315 If it worked for you, mark the question as solved by clicking on the check mark next to the answer.