# Passing variable to sed command in tcl

Tags: sed, tcl

I am having a issue where i am trying to substitute a variable in sed command while executing it in TCL shell.
Below is what i tried.

```
set variable 5 
exec  sed "s/test1\$/test1;test1 $variable/g" file1 > file2
```

I see below error.
 Error: sed: -e expression #1, char 75: unknown option to `s'
        Use error_info for more info. (CMD-013)

I have tried some links on stack overflow but that did not help.
[Using a Variable in a sed command called in Tcl Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563137/using-a-variable-in-a-sed-command-called-in-tcl-script)

Answer (score 2):

The general approach is correct. Try this<sup>1</sup>:

```
▶ expect
expect1.1> set var /bin/sh
/bin/sh
expect1.2> exec sed -n "s%:$var\$%:/bin/bash%p" /etc/passwd
root:*:0:0:System Administrator:/var/root:/bin/bash
expect1.3> exec sed -n "s%:$var\$%:/bin/bash%p" /etc/passwd > /tmp/log
```

Analysing your error message:

```
Error: sed: -e expression #1, char 75: unknown option to `s'
```

Note that sed received at least 75 characters- far more than in your code example. Does that help you to figure out what went wrong? If not, update with the actual code you tried.

---

<sup>1</sup> Noting that expect just adds some extensions onto TCL, and I don't have TCL on my laptop.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks i got it :)